# If a base goes without power long enough will all my plants/fish die?

Tags: subnautica

I'm new to *Subnautica*, and have just started building deeper bases powered by bioreactors. This is working well, but every time I dive down to the base I am scared that; the power went out, all my plants died, and I won't have enough air to double back up to the surface. Occasionally power was out when I arrived and my plants didn't die. I don't know if that is because I got there quickly enough, or if my plants simply won't die.

Right now I'm fueling my bioreactor with marblemelons. In the future I hope to transition to using fish when I get the alien containment tank. As such I'd like an answer that applies to food like marblemelons, and fish in an alien containment tank/aquarium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plants and the aquariums do not require power.  They therefore will be fine should the power cut out.

Plants don't require oxygen to survive, and fish inside the aquarium do not need oxygen either. So even if the base ran completely out of oxygen, they will be fine.

Comment: And, to expand on the question, if there is a hull breach and the base gets flooded, does the non-aquatic flora get damaged/destroyed? If yes, does it do so after the water surface reaches a certain level or is it instant? Would one have enough time to react and repair/reinforce the base?

Comment: @Eternal_Light not sure.  Maybe you should ask a separate question and see what answers you get?